# Ошибка "PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1"

Tags: php

Прочитал несколько тем но все бестолку.... Массив такой вроде есть с таким ключём но все равно пишет ошибку в ссш.... Вот код:

```
   $name[1] = "";
          if($item->getCustomName() !== "") $name = explode(" ", $item->getCustomName());
          if($name[1] == "§fПродавец§a"){
              $this->setContent($player -1);
              $player->getLevel()->addSound(new ClickSound($player));
              $this->id[$nick] = -1;
              $tid = explode("", $name[1]); $tid = $tid[0];
```

И да я знаю я 0 в PHP

Comment: что возвращает `$item->getCustomName()` ? `var_dump($name)`, либо `print_r($name)` и посмотрите, что лежит в нём и под каким индексом

Comment: А что он должен возвращать? return true?

Comment: Полагаю, что строка которая по пробелам разбивается на элементы массива, но что-то идет не так (в самой функции, которая отдает строку). Массив не формируется (формируется криво), либо [1] индекса нет

Answer (score 0):

Советую пройтись дебагером и посмотреть, в крайнем случае делайте var_dump() массивов после каждой строки и смотрите что там лежит, например после строки

```
if($item->getCustomName() !== "") $name = explode(" ", $item->getCustomName());
var_dump($name);
```